# Sum of the digits of two consecutive integers divisible by 17?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that the digit sums of $n$ and $n + 1$ are both divisible by $17$ or prove that no such solution exists.

My question was inspired when I couldn't find the correct solution to this similar question on brilliant: https://brilliant.org/problems/think-big/?group=UW1p9jvkDneH

I only have a fairly basic understanding of number theory and was wondering how this difficult problem could be broken down in to smaller parts that are easier to understand, or even a simple approach that I haven't spotted yet.

Note that I have change the number from 10 in the original question to 17 in my question so as to preserve the challenge of the original question.

Comment: hint. I would think the last digit of $n$ must be 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $ds(n) : \{0,\ldots,9\}^+ \to \mathbb{Z}$ the digit sum of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ in decimal representation, $(n)_{10}$.
Let $u$ be a prefix base 10 digit string.

If there is no carrying happening when increasing $n \to n + 1$, the number string is of the form $(n)_{10} = ud$, with $d \in \{ 0, \ldots 8 \}$, and we have:
$$
ds(ud) = ds(u) + d \\
ds((n+1)_{10}) = ds(u) + d + 1 
$$
so not both can vanish modulo $17$ (or any other number greater $1$).

For a number with carrying happening, we have:
$$
ds(u(10^k - 1)_{10}) = ds(u) + 9k  \\
ds(u(10^k)_{10}) = ds(u) + 1 
$$
So for the lower number we choose the smallest number with $ds(u) = 16$. This would be $79$. But it ends with a $9$ and we need the carrying process to stop, so it should not end with a $9$. The next candidate seems to be $88$.

For the upper number $k=2$ already leaves the needed rest one (modulo $17$). Test:
$$
ds(8899) = 16 + 18 = 34 = 2 \cdot 17 \\
ds(8900) = 17
$$